# Is a Tesla Valve a good fit for this requirement (prevent heavy load accidentally crashing downard but less restriction otherwise)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, hydraulics

I want to design a hydraulic platform that allows/ensures:

1. The **GRADUAL DESCENT** of a heavy load (e.g. a FULL shipping cargo container) from a height H1 to height H2 (where H1 > H2) - without the possibility of the heavy load crashing down suddenly
2. The **GRADUAL ASCENT** of same heavy load from a height H2 to H1 (where H2 < H1).

I have been pondering if a [Tesla Valve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_valve) could be use to "impede" the movement in one direction (downward), so that (subject to weight being within tolerance limits), there is no chance (all things being equal), that the load will suddenly crash downward.

Questions:

1. Is this a feasible use of a Tesla Valve - and is there any real world use of a Tesla Valve in such a scenario?
2. Any pros and cons with this approach that I must be aware of before I put pen to paper and start designing?

Comment: So that link you give points out that Tesla valves work better with pulsing flows. How does that fit with your application?

Comment: It should be possible to add a "pulsator" mechanism to "agitate" the fluid flow, to enhance the effect.

Comment: Short answer is no. Use mechanicals such as a worm gear drive that must be powered in both directions. The gear can be driven hydraulically of course. For less critical needs, use conventional hydraulic speed control valves on the cylinders. These can be set up with fail safes and leak detection systems as well.

Comment: http://www.valvehydraulic.info/hydraulic-circuit-design/hydraulic-fail-safe-circuit.html

Comment: @PhilSweet Thanks for saving me from reinventing the wheel. Perhaps you could elaborate some more in an answer?

Comment: has any of the tesla valve fans looked into the difference in pressure loss between both flow directions? IIRC it was slightly less than a factor two (in microfluidic applications. Likely scale dependent). this should be part of the design consideration.

Comment: It sounds to me that you need an independent safety brake. Rupture of the hydraulic hose between the actuator and your speed regulator could be fatal. Have a look of the history of the Otis safety lift (elevator) for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.chemicalprocessing.com/blogs/chemical-reaction/100-year-old-tesla-valve-is-cool-but-not-well-suited-for-industry/
According to this article , the tesla valve fails during high pressure and high flow

Answer (score 0):

### It might but there are better alternatives.

All the Tesla "valve" does is provide restricted one-way flow.  There are already plenty of check valves that will allow partial flow but not full flow.  The Tesla valve probably helps with some of the FMEA possibilities, but probably not all of them, and in this case you would have to turn your motion into fluid flow just to get started.

Other options:  Check valves (if this is somehow already related to hydraulics), worm gears, centrifugal clutches, elevator emergency brakes, etc.  The best solution is to prevent the failure in the first place.